# Python : Do we need to add exception block while importing built in modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a novice question.

Consider the below code block :

```
try:
    import os
except ImportError as error:
    print " Unable to import buildin module os"
    raise error
```

Do we need to add exception block while importing python built-in modules(like above? What would cause to fail importing a built in module?

Can someone point at python documentation explaining this theory?

Comment: Can you explain why *you* think it would be necessary?

Comment: Yes, That's a bad thought. Just wanted a clear justification as to know why it is wrong?

Comment: It's been a couple of years. You should select an answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons that the code in the question is pretty much pointless.

First of all, it does not add any new information. The error is just reraised. The printout adds no new information that isn't already in the error and stack trace.

Second, as [@RemcoGerlich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481523/2988730) points out, you are asking specifically about builtin modules. It would make sense to react to the absence of an optional module by either finding a replacement or turning off program features, but there's nothing much you can do in response to your platform being broken.

Failure of builtin imports is never addressed in the documentation explicitly to the best of my knowledge. Builtin module imports can fail for any of the reasons a normal import can fail. Builtins are a collection of Python files and C-extensions (in CPython at least). Modifying, replacing, deleting any of these files can lead to anything from import failures to the interpreter not starting up at all. Setting the wrong file permissions can have a similar effect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Will ensure to close as per timeline.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer: it doesn't help your program much to catch exceptions that you can't do anything about. Some file is missing -- you can report it, maybe ask the user again, or perhaps it is known that this sometimes happens and you can give a clear error message explaining why. Some API call fails -- maybe it can be retried, or someone needs to receive a message that a service is down.

But something as basic as this... First, it never happens (I've never seen `import os` fail in twenty years). Second, if that fails, there's nothing your program can usefully do (if this fails, chances are `print` also fails). And also, the library documentation doesn't say that this is something that can happen.

You have to rely on the basic system working. Only catch exceptions when it is known that they could be raised and you have a way to deal with them.